# Django - Ajax request aborted without error after 30s

Tags: ajax, django

I have an ajax request that trigger a function that could be ressource intensive for the server. After 30 seconds the request is aborted without error from the server. If I use a smaller dataset, the request finish successfully.

Actually, I am using the runserver of Django.

What could be the cause of this abortion?

**Edit:**

Curiously a server error appeared few minutes after the abortion:

```
[22/Aug/2014 12:38:20] "POST /basqui/layer/shapefile/simplify HTTP/1.1" 200 16
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 212, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 270, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 194, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] Une connexion Útablie a ÚtÚ abandonnÚe par un logiciel de v
otre ordinateur h¶te
[22/Aug/2014 12:38:20] "POST /basqui/layer/shapefile/simplify HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually an AJAX-Request has a certain timeout. For jQuery you can set the timeout (see `timeout` in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)).

The error in Django results in the fact that in wants to send the response to the request on a connection which already died (because of the timeout).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that info, the default value of the timeout is 3000ms so that's clear!